# What contribution dates does the default iATS recur job process?

Tags: iats

Does it only run recurring transactions from the current day the job is run (by default) based on the 'next contribution date' field, or does it attempt to run scheduled transactions from past dates as well?

We ran a limited trial and experienced it running a few contributions from days prior to the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurring contributions job will process all recurring series that have a status in progress and that are due or are past due (i.e. have a next scheduled contribution date either today or in the past).